# URL is not changing while page is updated

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to set wait for IE instance wherein Source URL is not getting changed however the information is updated on the page. When this happens page goes blur and I cannot control it with VBA code.

```
Sub WaitIE()
While IE.Busy = True
    Application.Wait 500
Wend
While IE.readyState <> 4
    Application.Wait 500
Wend

While IE.document Is Nothing
    Application.Wait 500
Wend
End Sub
```

`<td>
   <input type="text" name="SELECTED" tabindex="0"  size="8" maxlength="8" onchange="document.FORM.MODIFIED.value=1" style class="text" onblur="" />
  </td>
  <td><input type="submit" tabindex="-1" name="View" value="View" onclick="return view_e()" title="Click to view selected" class="button" />
  </td>"`

to upload the page -

```
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

I = 0
While I < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(I).Name = "SELECTED" Then
        objCollection(I).Value = "12345"
    End If
    If objCollection(I).Type = "submit" And objCollection(I).Name = "View" Then ' submit button if found and set
        Set objElement = objCollection(I)
    End If
    I = I + 1
Wend
objElement.Click

WaitIE
```

Comment: You may need to show your navigate code and explain how you are changing the page, is it the html you posted?

Comment: Yes, I am searching the tagname("name") which is "View" and then clicking on it.

Comment: You will probably need to know what return view_e() is doing so that you can check to see if it has completed. Since the URL doesn't change, I believe that is your best bet.